# Iterating over Typescript Map

Tags: typescript, dictionary, iterator

I'm trying to iterate over a typescript map but I keep getting errors and I could not find any solution yet for such a trivial problem.

My code is:

```
myMap : Map<string, boolean>;
for(let key of myMap.keys()) {
   console.log(key);
}
```

And I get the Error:

> Type 'IterableIteratorShim<[string, boolean]>' is not an array type or a string type.

Full Stack Trace:

```
 Error: Typescript found the following errors:
  /home/project/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-q4GtzHgb.tmp/0/src/app/project/project-data.service.ts (21, 20): Type 'IterableIteratorShim<[string, boolean]>' is not an array type or a string type.
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler._doIncrementalBuild (/home/project/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/broccoli-typescript.js:115:19)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.build (/home/project/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/broccoli-typescript.js:43:10)
    at /home/project/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:152:21
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/home/project/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/home/project/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/home/project/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1019:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/home/project/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

I'm using angular-cli beta5 and typescript 1.8.10 and my target is es5.
Has anyone had this Problem?

Comment: See this answer from github https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3164#issuecomment-104443321

Comment: I made a silly mistake, in JS, don't do `map["key"] = "value"`, but `map.set("key", "value")`

Answer (score 385, accepted):

You could use `Map.prototype.forEach((value, key, map) => void, thisArg?) : void` instead

Use it like this:

```
myMap.forEach((value: boolean, key: string) => {
    console.log(key, value);
});
```

Comment: Just ran into this. Doesn't look like TypeScript is respecting the spec for map iteration, at least according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which specifies a for-of loop. `.forEach` is sub-optimal, since you can't break it , AFAIK

Comment: dunno why its value then key. Seems backwards.

Comment: @PaulRooney it's like that probably to harmonize with `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: How to stop this iteration process if we found what we need?

Comment: @Samjones Using `return;` in a foreach is the same as `continue` in a normal for loop

Comment: @monamona And, pray, what would the equivalent of `break` be, since Samjones explicitly mentioned **breaking**.... The only way I know is to have an outside flag `skipToEnd = false`, instead of `break;` put `skipToEnd = true; return` and at the very beginning of the function you have to add `if (skipToEnd) return;`... not very elegant.

Comment: For typescript, I use 
`Object.entries(myMap).forEach((i) => { const key = i[0]; const val = i[1]; ... })`

Answer (score 162):

## es6

```
for (let [key, value] of map) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

## es5

```
for (let entry of Array.from(map.entries())) {
    let key = entry[0];
    let value = entry[1];
}
```

Comment: The es6 version given above is not compiling in strict mode.

Comment: this question is about typescript, not plain js

Comment: Why using "let"? Why not "const"? You won't change entry in most cases. "key" and "value" neither I guess.

Comment: @Stephane if you are not using that variable, you can replace it with _ to avoid compile-time errors.

Answer (score 62):

Just use `Array.from()` method to convert it to an `Array`:

```
myMap : Map<string, boolean>;
for(let key of Array.from( myMap.keys()) ) {
   console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: Converting maps is a very performance-hungry operation and not the correct way to solve a problem that's essentially just the compiler hiding core parts of the language. Just `<any>`-cast the map to iterate it with for-of.

Comment: Beware: I thought that @Kilves suggestion above to cast the Map to "any" was an elegant workaround. When I did it, the code compiled and ran without complaint, but the Map was not actually iterated -- the content of the loop never executed.  The `Array.from()` strategy proposed here did work for me.

Comment: I tried that too, it didn't work for me either, which is even stupider considering it *is* part of ES6 and should "just work" on most browsers. But I guess our angular overlords use some magic mumbo jumbo in zone.js to make it not work, because they hate ES6. Sigh.

Comment: @Kilves `foreach` doesn't support fully async/await

Comment: @Han I know, that's why I said for-of, not foreach.

Comment: @Kilves yeah, maybe I've misread somewhere

Comment: For me, `for (let key of myMap.keys())` worked both with `ES5` and `ES6`. No casting, no `Array.from()` used.

Answer (score 49):

This worked for me. TypeScript Version: 2.8.3

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myMap)) { 
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

Comment: I got this to work by changing Object.entries(myMap) to just myMap.entries(). I like this answer because it avoids the error handling pitfalls of .forEach calls.

Comment: Worth noting that if your `target` in `tsconfig` is `es5` this throws an error, but with `es6` works correctly. You can also just do `for (const [key, value] of myMap)` when targeting `es6`

Comment: This is potentially problematic because keys will be treated as `string`, while it possible to have a Map with e.g. `number` keys.

Comment: This worked for me on `"typescript": "~4.7.4"`

Answer (score 41):

Using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

Iterate over the **keys**:

```
Array.from(myMap.keys()).forEach(key => console.log(key));
```

Iterate over the **values**:

```
Array.from(myMap.values()).forEach(value => console.log(value));
```

Iterate over the **entries**:

```
Array.from(myMap.entries()).forEach(entry => console.log('Key: ' + entry[0] + ' Value: ' + entry[1]));
```

Comment: Not sure why, I have the map like Map<String, CustomeClass>. none of the above methods worked except Array.from(myMap.values()).forEach(value => console.log(value));.

Answer (score 26):

Per the [TypeScript 2.3 release notes on "New `--downlevelIteration`"](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#new---downleveliteration):

> `for..of statements`, Array Destructuring, and Spread elements in Array, Call, and New expressions support Symbol.iterator in ES5/E3 if available when using `--downlevelIteration`

**This is not enabled by default!** Add `"downlevelIteration": true` to your `tsconfig.json`, or pass `--downlevelIteration` flag to `tsc`, to get full iterator support.

With this in place, you can write `for (let keyval of myMap) {...}` and `keyval`'s type will be automatically inferred.

---

Why is this turned off by default? According to TypeScript contributor [@aluanhaddad](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3164#issuecomment-328587113),

> It is optional because it has a very significant impact on the size of generated code, and potentially on performance, for all uses of iterables (including arrays).

If you can target ES2015 (`"target": "es2015"` in `tsconfig.json` or `tsc --target ES2015`) or later, enabling `downlevelIteration` is a no-brainer, but if you're targeting ES5/ES3, you might benchmark to ensure iterator support doesn't impact performance (if it does, you might be better off with `Array.from` conversion or `forEach` or some other workaround).

Comment: is this ok or dangerous to enable this when using Angular ?

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me.

```
Object.keys(myMap).map( key => {
    console.log("key: " + key);
    console.log("value: " + myMap[key]);
});
```

Comment: With this the keys will always be strings though

Comment: ERROR!: this only works if you've NOT used myMap as a Map (e.g. with `myMap.set(key, value)`), but instead as an object (e.g. `myMap[key]=value`). That's also why you'll only see string keys. Prove it with `Object.keys(new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2]]))` .

Comment: Tried this with your suggestion and this still works for me.

Comment: Map's are assigned with `m.set(key, val)`; Objects are assigned with `o[key]=val`. Maps are also Objects, but so are e.g. dates (try `d=new Date(); d['a']=1; Object.keys(d)`). Initialize a Map: `m=new Map([['a', 1]])`, misuse it as an Object: `m['b']=2`, `[...m.keys()]` has key `a` from initialization; `Object.keys(m)` has `b` from its Object assignment.

If you doing Object assignment, there's no reason to use a Map instead of just a `{}`. It won't give you the advantages of a Map (performant, non-string keys) and it will take a few more clock cycles to construct.

Answer (score 13):

You can also apply the array map method to the Map.entries() iterable:

```
[...myMap.entries()].map(
     ([key, value]: [string, number]) => console.log(key, value)
);
```

Also, as noted in other answers, you may have to enable down level iteration in your tsconfig.json (under compiler options):

```
  "downlevelIteration": true,
```

Comment: This feature was introduced in TypeScript 2.3. The problem occured with TypeScript  1.8.10

Comment: If you can't use "downlevelIteration", you can use:
`const projected = Array.from(myMap).map(...);`

Answer (score 9):

I'm using latest TS and node (v2.6 and v8.9 respectively) and I can do:

```
let myMap = new Map<string, boolean>();
myMap.set("a", true);
for (let [k, v] of myMap) {
    console.log(k + "=" + v);
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you first had to set `"downlevelIteration": true` in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: I do not have `downlevelIteraton` set, my target is `es2017` however.

Comment: Can't i do this for Map<string, CustomClass[]> element ? compiler says it is not an array of type or string type.

Comment: this doesn't work for me on 2.8 - I get `Type 'Map<K, V>' is not an array type or a string type.`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Any "lib" I should be using?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

On Typescript 3.5 and Angular 8 LTS, it was required to cast the type as follows:

```
for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(someMap)) {
    console.log(k, v)
}
```

Comment: This got nothing to do with Angular though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple explanation to use it in an HTML document.

If you have a Map of types (key, array) then you initialise the array this way:

```
public cityShop: Map<string, Shop[]> = new Map();
```

And to iterate over it, you create an array from key values.

Just use it as an array as in:

```
keys = Array.from(this.cityShop.keys());
```

Then, in HTML, you can use:

```
*ngFor="let key of keys"
```

Inside this loop, you just get the array value with:

```
this.cityShop.get(key)
```

Done!

Comment: Just a small correction: the HTML you mean happen to be an Angular Template, not plain HTML. Please write Angular Template instead of HTML, because plain HTML does not understand *ngFor.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using `Array.from( myMap.keys() )` to get an array of keys in my VSCode extension that's implemented using node.js, but it did not work, even after adding `"downlevelIteration": true` to my tsconfig.json with the target set to `es2017` as suggested by [Ahmed Fasih](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48353980/4596058) and others.

What ultimately worked was [Jason Slobotski's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53641411/4596058) suggestion to use `Object.keys`:

```
let keys = Object.keys(myMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const test_map=new Map();
test_map.set("hello",1);
test_map.set("world",2);
for (let it=test_map.entries(),val=(it.next().value);val!==undefined;val=(it.next().value)){
    console.log(val);
}
// ["hello", 1]
// ["world", 2]
```

See [Map.prototype.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really like nested functions, you can also iterate over the keys:

```
myMap : Map<string, boolean>;
for(let key of myMap) {
   if (myMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify({key: key, value: myMap[key]}));
   }
}
```

Note, you have to filter out the non-key iterations with the `hasOwnProperty`, if you don't do this, you get a warning or an error.

Comment: how to iterate over map in html? it doesn't seem to work at all.  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in model.myMap"> {{key}}. </div>

Comment: @powerfade917 It doesn't work, it works only for arrays because angular is a pile of trash. But ask this as a new question and so you will learn, that angular is not a pile of trash, but you have to convert it to an array. Note, also you are not the top of the top of the programming, because you are seemingly incapable to differentiate between angular and typescript.

Answer (score -3):

```
let map = new Map();

map.set('a', 2);
map.set('b', 4);
map.set('c', 6);
map.set('d', 7);

for(let key of map) 
{ 
    console.log(key[0], "----" key[1]) 
}
```

**Output -**

```
a ---- 2
b ---- 4
c ---- 6
d ---- 7
```