# TypeScript Map: key and value swapped on iteration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I come with a simplified question about TypeScript where my "key" and "value" are getting switched. To demonstrate the issue I have the following the map, which I store in file by itself:

Parts.ts

```
export const PART_DATA : Map<string, string> = new Map( 
[
    [ 'PI',  'Piping' ],
    [ 'TC',  'Truck Components' ],
    [ 'BE',  'Brake Equipment' ]
]);
```

... and we will call my other file where I implement this Map, ProcessParts.ts, which will look like so:

```
  import {Component, OnInit, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
  import {PART_DATA} from './Parts';    

  export class ProcessParts {

      ngOnInit(){    
        PART_DATA.forEach((key: string, value: string) => {
          console.log("here is " + key + ', ' + value);
        });
      }
  }
```

...and our output will begin to read like so:

```
here is Piping, PI
```

... when the key and value should be swapped.  It is not a huge problem, but I am using a couple maps set up like this `PART_DATA` example, but this is the first time I have seen this problem when I am iterating over this map (this this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699320/iterating-over-typescript-map) on iterating iterating over a ts map).  For clarity, I need to iterate over the Map in the first place so I can display some options to the UI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The callback in the forEach method on Map takes arguments in the following order:

`function(value,key,map)`

The correct syntax would be:

```
 PART_DATA.forEach((value: string, key: string) => {
          console.log("here is " + key + ', ' + value);
        });
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach