# Why some of these code cannot iterate values in a map in typescript?

Tags: typescript, codepen

I am trying out some typescript idioms as described in the answers to this SO question ([Iterating over Typescript Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699320/iterating-over-typescript-map)) in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kongakong/pen/daKPWr?editors=0111).

Here is my code.

```
class KeyType {
  style: number;
  constructor(style) {
    this.style = style;  
  };
}

function test() {


  const someMap = new Map<KeyType, number>();
  someMap.set(new KeyType(style=199), 5);
  someMap.set(new KeyType(style=67), 90);

 console.log('test of 1')

  for (let [k, m] of someMap) {
    console.log(`1 k ${k} m ${m}`);
  }

   console.log('test of 2')

  for (let [k, m] of someMap.entries()) {
    console.log(`2 k ${k} m ${m}`);
  }

   console.log('test Object entries')

  for (let [k, m] of Object.entries(someMap)) {
    console.log(`3 k ${k} m ${m}`);
  }

  console.log('for each')

  someMap.forEach((v, id) => console.log(`3 v ${v} id ${id}`))

  Array.from(someMap.entries()).forEach(entry =>
    console.log(`4 k ${entry[0].style} m ${entry[1]}`)
  )

  const ar = Array.from(someMap.keys());
  console.log(ar[0].style);

}
```

What I do not understand is: all the `forEach` method work as expected, but the `for (let [k,m] of someMap) {...` just do not seem to work at all.

Could it be a problem with codepen's typescript configuration? Did I make any mistake with `test of 1`, `test of 2` and `test Object entries` in the above code?

I wanted to install `ts-node` to test locally but so far I have gotten another set of issues regarding its installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's fix the errors you have.

```
someMap.set(new KeyType(style=199), 5);
```

This is not valid JavaScript/TypeScript syntax. If you want `199` to be your argument, write it as:

```
someMap.set(new KeyType(199), 5);
```

The second thing is how your `KeyType` class is serialized for the purpose of printing to the console.

```
  for (let [k, m] of someMap) {
    console.log(`1 k ${k} m ${m}`);
  }
```

Here, `k` represents `KeyType` which in your scope represents a class. JavaScript runtime serializes classes by returning `"[object] Object"`, which I presume is not what you wanted.

If your intention was to log the `style` of your `KeyType`, replace it with this:

```
  for (let [k, m] of someMap) {
    console.log(`1 k ${k.style} m ${m}`);
  }
```

You can check out the final result in [TypeScript Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDSCmBPAKogDvaBvAUNaEALoiPAFzQB2ArgLYBG8ATgNx7TAD2lRT1whTkwAUREuSp1GTAJTZ2+QgAsAlhAB0Y0tAC8BYqRb52AXzYmcOAGbVKAld2iF4RYXNz4uPQgU614ALJgaLpU8ADu0EFoADwIKOjwADSSDMwAfG5s+BB+gcGa8ITClBFwSKgYwgCMAJy1MikArDLZvv7RhcWlkfGV8MIAbADsjdC1AAytlhzcuaTqIJwA5sIA5M5E0JxW0NVrMjPQVkLQwqQ+ANoA1im0ALrbu7kdwe4KszycC0urAAbVaDXaAAEiw100BngJmgtFBWFoJj+03wFgUXnm8EWK3Wmx8O2gACYDkcTkwzhdoDc7o8CS98mh1PBKIQmCoXG53vhPHNvljfsI-oSgfCIVpobD4YjkW00dyMXzsasNi4fAB5egAK3gAmgzNZ7IgJPYZIpRSpt1htN2Gu1AiZLLZHPp0RkXPlvJ+OL+AGYRWDrjC4WDpSjoHLPpiletTfAwMAlMacnlOmSAKLxpTCYQANxSKgAJnIdOlI4qBb7oDn4TmYYX4YXIeIkW6jgBBJhMMCIdRWJh+UQpgr6p0QTm9oQZhPCEeIXTpD4Kr3-AAs-qws8uE3uTdIQfhm+q9xb7EO7AxPjA5L0Ha7Pb7A5dBWuSDHbraS-5OKvW534umOBoniWSWAA9AAVOBeDgdAyCqDAajHKc-QAMrAGyaA+IIThMHGWHwQQ6EqJh0CQKRsKcAW1ALNBoE4PAAAeaBCFhiRUJwnAhHoYCUIgLBAA).

---

**Note**: a common source of confusion is variable overshadowing. Your class is called `KeyType`, but there is also a global type called the same.

```
type KeyType = "public" | "private" | "secret";
```

If your code lives in a file without any import/export statements, it's going to be treated as a *script* and not a *module*. It means the global type will take precedence and if you try to call it by `new KeyType()`, you will receive a compile-time error:

> 'KeyType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: DId not catch any of these at all in codepen. I got to sort out a local env to do quick ts test ☹️

Comment: Sometimes it's better to use [TypeScript playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/) instead of Codepen. ;-)